# after running aspnet_regsql.exe , do I have to init the db with data? how?

Tags: asp.net-membership

I ran aspnet_regsql.exe to setup .net membership tables etc.

What do I run to create my application so I can add users etc?

Answer (score 2):

in your visual studio, go to "Website -> ASP.NET Configuration" then a web application will start. there you can add user etc.

Comment: In addition to what Arief recommends: 

ASP.NET Configuration will launch the built in development server along with the ASP.NET Website Configuration Tool. This is where you can enable Roles and add Users